# Django- how to hyphenate TextField in URLs

Tags: django, url, django-models

I am trying to make my model so that the URL slug is hyphenated between spaces in the slug field by default.  The slug should be limited to only the first six words in `TextField`.  The `TextField()` called `questionToProblem` in the same model.  Here's what I have:

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    free = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = Free)


    questionToProblem = models.TextField()
    solutionToProblem = models.TextField()

slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

plainText = models.TextField(default= 'temp')
profile = models.JSONField(default=dict, blank=True) #default is assigned on the recommendation of django docs. DO NOT CHANGE
comments = GenericRelation(Comment)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs) #create the problem
    cosine = Cosine(2)

    self.plainText = LatexNodes2Text().latex_to_text(str(self))
    self.profile = cosine.get_profile(self.plainText)
    super().save(update_fields=['plainText', 'profile',]) #update the neccessary fields

    for query in SavedQuery.objects.all():
        query_profile = cosine.get_profile(query.query)
        similarity = cosine.similarity_profiles(query_profile, self.profile)

        if similarity >= 0.25 and self not in query.results.all():
            query.results.add(self)
            query.save()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('questionToProblem',)

def get_url(self):
    return reverse('solution_details', args = [self.topic.slug, self.slug])

def __str__(self):
    return self.questionToProblem
```

My views.py:

```
def displaySolution(request, topic_slug, problem_slug):
    try:
        solution = Problem.objects.get(topic__slug = topic_slug, slug = problem_slug)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    return render(request, 'solution.html', {'solution' : solution})
```

Ideally, here's what I want the URL to look like, if the `questionToProblem` was `"How many bananas do I have in total?"`, and the `Topic` key was `"modeltopic"`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/modeltopic/How-many-bananas-do-I-have
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very clear. Are you looking for a function that can convert a string to a slug? You can use [`slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify).

Comment: I'm looking for a function that turns a TextField into a slug with hyphens in between spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your slug field to include blank will help you out with the autosaving bit in the admin. Otherwise the form will complain that it needs a value.

```
slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True, blank=True)
```

Add a method for the save something like the following. This may not be the best way given you want to use the TextField as the slug source - this may become a performance issue, but if your text is relatively short, and there are few 'new' Problems on a relative basis you may be alright. Use Django's `slugify` to deal with alphanumerics, trailing spaces, underscores, hyphens and the like, then `split` the text on <del>space</del> hyphen, taking a max of six words (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) which then get   joined (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) back together as a string each separated with a hyphen.

```
def save(self):
    if not self.slug:
        # self.slug = slugify(' '.join(self.questionToProblem.split(' ')[:6]))
        # or take advantage of split's second argument
        # self.slug = slugify(' '.join(self.questionToProblem.split(' ', 5)))
        # or to take Selcuk's suggestion:
        # coding on the fly here in S/O so no guarantee on this syntax :)
        self.slug = '-'.join(slugify(self.questionToProblem).split('-', 5))
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note the use of `slugify` which you can import with:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
```

Comment: It might be a better idea to split _after_ the slugify using `-` as the separator as words might have been separated by punctuation instead of spaces (e.g. `Hello,world`).

Comment: you'll probably want to have a uniqueness check with a loop that handles how you want to manage that (adding an id or index as a suffix perhaps)